# "He as good as called slob"

Tags: phrase-meaning

what does **"He as good as called"** mean in the sentence ‘***He as good as called me a slob!’ ‘Well, if the cap fits***

Comment: "He may as well have called me a slob."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"as good as" is a way to indicate a circumlocution, or a way to say that you're very close to the indicated state.

I can call someone fat, dirty, sloppy, and ungroomed.  I didn't technically call that person a slob, but I as good as called them a slob.

Or I can say "That operating system is as good as dead", meaning that it's almost dead.

Comment: In short " as good as" = "close to" or "almost like" ?

Comment: "close to" or "almost".  Not "almost like"